# How to make a car door hinge upwards?

Tags: animation, axis

I have arrived in Blender animation hell and I need help.
I'm trying to make a car door open by hinging it upwards - the problem I have is that the edge where the car door and bodywork meet is not perpendicular to the global axis.

[image]

When I set the origin / 3d cursor to that edge and try to rotate the door upwards it clips with the bodywork on the right side and disconnects from the body on the left.

[image]

Any pointers you guys can give me an fixing the rotation and make the door open nicely?
(e.g. is it possible to create a hinge of som sorts?)

Thanks

---

Update:
@haaringertroll @Mdkai

Thanks for your comments - it works but I have a new problem with the bottom part of the door. (also folding)
I parented a new second empty to the top door part and parented the bottom part of the door to the second empty.
When animating it seems to disconnect and eventually end up in the correct location.
Any way to fix that disconnecting part?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an "Empty"-object to where your 3D-Cursor now is. This you can rotate so that one of its axes aligns with the desired axis of rotation.
Then, select the door, select the Empty and press "Crtl - P" to parent the door to the empty.
With the transform mode set to "Local", you can then rotate the empty and the door along with it around the desired axis

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments, I have updated my first post with an additional question.

Comment: In that case, you are probably better off using an armature, this gives you better control over the rotation of the individual objects.

Comment: Two bones did the trick - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to align the *Empty* with an edge you set the snapping to *Edge*, affect *rotate* and *translate* and also turn on *Align rotation to target*

This will snap the *Empty* on to any edge and also align the axis along that edge.

[image]